# Android onClickListener - Android Studio bug or my own mistake?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The previous snippet of code has been written down by the aid of random sites and answers from StackOverflow, but somehow not working. I should add that I am an absolute beginner at making apps and my experience with Java is very limited as well.

The errors is the following:

- "setOnClickListener": Marked red.
- "public void onClick(View v) {": Here "v" is marked red, for some
  reason. It continues being red in "String text = v.toString();".
- The program also finds my semicolon redundant at the end of the
  snippet.

I am using the beta of Android Studio on Elementary OS, using OpenJDK.

```
Button button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
    button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = v.toString();
            displayPassword(text);
        }
    });
```

I could have made any number of mistakes, that's for sure. But any nudge in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Comment: Why "View.OnClickListener"? Did you import the View and Button Types?

Comment: you remove that button_1.setOnClickListener( View.OnClickListener(){}, just button_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){} is ok

Comment: v.toString(),consider it.....

Comment: Everything is imported, removing View in "new View.OnClickListener()" makes that an error and v.toString() has been thought of. "String text = ((Button) v).getText().toString();"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is:Set the `onClick` in the `XML` file, and create the method in the current class.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="click" />

public void click(View arg0) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Graph that you should have to @Override the onClick method.  Not sure what's wrong with it there.  In fact, when I typed your example into Android Studio, I got 3 letters into OnClickListener and it automatically filled in the rest, including the @Override.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = v.toString();
            // do something with the text.
        }
    });
```

Also, I don't think v.toString() is going to get you any useful information. If you want the text off the button, you're going to want to cast it to a button then call getText():

```
Button button = (Button) v;
String text = button.getText().toString();
```

or, you could do:

```
String text = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
```

Simply calling v.toString() is going to get you a description of that button, not the text on it.

Comment: Might be some flaw in my version, shall see about an update. And yes, I do know about the text, it was just to get something out on the screen. Fixed that shortly after when I had solved my button-issue. :)

Comment: cool cool.  Yeah, I think it might be a flaw in your project setup.  I wonder if it's importing some other kind of Button (one that doesn't have an OnClickListener).  Good luck.  Project structure issues have been pretty common for me working with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to @Override the onClick method.

```
Button button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
    button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override  
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = v.toString();
        displayPassword(text);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried with @Override, got marked red. "Annotation not allowed here".

Answer (score 0):

Just press " ctrl+shift+o " and add 1 library which you shows on screen prob solved